# get element by class in nested divs

Tags: jquery

I need to get with jquery the specific closest message-input text after the class "edit" was clicked.

notice that this code is multiplied so

```
$(".message-input").text()
```

is not good for me..

here is the code:

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <div class="3a"></div>
      <div class="3b">
        <div class="3b-inner">
        <span>aaa</span>
        <span>aaa</span>
        <p class="message-input">Get this message after click</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="3c">
      <i></i>
      <ul>
        <li class="edit">On click this button</li>
        <li class="delete"></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without using class $(this).parent().parent().prev('div').find('p:first').text() here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dq0vjf1e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the structure you posted is repeated, this is one way:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).closest("div.3").find(".message-input").text()
})
```

Example:

```js
    $(".edit").click(function(){
        var text = $(this).closest("div.3").find(".message-input").text();
        console.log(text)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <div class="3a"></div>
      <div class="3b">
        <div class="3b-inner">
        <span>aaa</span>
        <span>aaa</span>
        <p class="message-input">Get this message after click 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="3c">
      <i></i>
      <ul>
        <li class="edit">On click this button</li>
        <li class="delete"></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <div class="3a"></div>
      <div class="3b">
        <div class="3b-inner">
        <span>aaa</span>
        <span>aaa</span>
        <p class="message-input">Get this message after click 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="3c">
      <i></i>
      <ul>
        <li class="edit">On click this button</li>
        <li class="delete"></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <div class="3a"></div>
      <div class="3b">
        <div class="3b-inner">
        <span>aaa</span>
        <span>aaa</span>
        <p class="message-input">Get this message after click 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="3c">
      <i></i>
      <ul>
        <li class="edit">On click this button</li>
        <li class="delete"></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain div.3 ?

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to find the closest  `message-input` in the div. This also assumes `div.3` is always going to be the required wrapper. That said, if the user always knows the class wrapper and that this class will always be closest and that there will only ever be one `message-input` class within it, then this solution would work.

Comment: @GiladAdar `<div class="3">`

Comment: @Vector - It is based on what the OP posted.

Comment: ok, thanks, i used closest with "prev", only that worked for me, i didn't understand what is div.3, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What this code says is:

From this clicked `.edit` element, look for the `div` before the closest parent `div` to find `.message-input`.

```js
$(".edit").on("click",function(){
  var myText = $(this).closest("div").prev("div").find(".message-input").html();
  console.log(myText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <div class="3a"></div>
      <div class="3b">
        <div class="3b-inner">
        <span>aaa</span>
        <span>aaa</span>
        <p class="message-input">Get this message after click</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="3c">
      <i></i>
      <ul>
        <li class="edit">On click this button</li>
        <li class="delete"></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```